# how can i use or implement Power BI feature in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, business-intelligence, powerpivot, powerview

I have been using Power BI features in Excel 2013 and was wondering what do I need to do to get them working in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Is your SharePoint Enterprise edition?

Comment: Yes its the SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by the "Power BI" features.  Power BI is an Office 365-based product which provides what is, in essence, a cloud-based SharePoint-esque environment for all your self-service BI functionality.

A lot of this functionality (but not all of it) is also available in SharePoint 2013 (and part of it in 2010).

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise allows you to make use of the following features:

- Sharing of Power Pivot models
- Power Pivot scheduled data refresh
- SSAS Tabular and multi-dimensional (SQL 2012 SP1 & SQL 2014 only)  data sources for Power View
- Power View report creation
- "Vanilla" SSRS reports

To manage/share your Power Pivot models and create Power View reports, you need to be able to add a Power Pivot Gallery to your SharePoint site.  This has several prerequisites, including an instance of SQL Server Analysis Services (2012/2014 BI or Enterprise Edition) in Power Pivot mode, and Reporting Services in SharePoint mode.

To do this, you need to follow the steps outlined in these two articles:

- [Power Pivot installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219067.aspx)
- [Reporting Services for SharePoint installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219068.aspx)

SharePoint 2013 does not support Q&A (the natural language query component of Power BI).